# PHP Variable and Function Inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, scope

Im getting the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: avg

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /var/www/html/#####/#####/res/calc_food.php on line 37
```

This is my PHP class:

```
//Base class for food calculator
abstract class Food {

    protected $avg;                                                 //Average per meal
    protected function equation() {return false;}                      //Equation for total

    //Sets
    public function setAverage($newAvg) {
        $this->$avg = $newAvg;
    }

    //Gets
    public function getAverage() {
        return $this->$avg;
    }

    public function getTotal() {
        $total = $this->equation();

        return $total;
    }
}

//Beef/lamb calculator
class Beef extends Food {

    protected $avg = 0.08037;

    protected function equation() {
        return (($this->$avg*14)-$this->$avg)*_WEEKS;                   //=(1.125-(1.125/14))*52.18;
    }
}
```

The line it is referring to:

```
return (($this->$avg*14)-$this->$avg)*_WEEKS;                   //=(1.125-(1.125/14))*52.18;
```

I'm not sure what the cause of this is. I've tried playing around with scopes. Basically I'm trying to change the base avg value, and the calculating equation for each new food item added, so that food->getTotal() will be different depending on the food child class used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->$avg
```

...will first evaluate $avg to whatever it may be (in this case, nothing), and then look *that* up in the $this object. 
You want:

```
$this->avg
```

which will look up the "avg" property of the $this object.

Comment: This was the problem, thank you. Is it still correct to use $this->$avg in the parent class functions?

Answer (score 1):

You must access properties **without** `$`:

```
$this->avg
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$this->avg // no $avg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use properties without $:

```
$this->property
```

instead of

```
$this->$property
```

correct line:

```
return (($this->avg*14)-$this->avg)*_WEEKS;
```